# How can we lower the risk of migrating from an old site to a new site?

Tags: user-behavior, e-commerce, testing-protocols

background knowledge about our app so you can have context :

- we are a multi-vendor B2B e-commerce website
- our users base is fairly small, with about 400+ active customers
- most of our users are middle-aged men and don't have much experience in using tech
- We have an old e-commerce site that was built using an old e-commerce platform, it served us well but we grew out of it and built our own custom e-commerce platform

these are the main risks we are worried about :

1. the new site's UX matches the old site by 60%-70% so because of our demographic we are very worried that not negligible part of users might get discouraged using the website and because we are a B2B site even a small percentage of users can equal a lot of orders/money.
2. when we launch the new site we don't want to kill the old site right away, we want to keep it running as a backup plan till we know for sure that the new site is stable, but that will raise a few concerns :
3. should we let users use the old site and place orders?
4. should we synchronize between the old DB and the new DB (it's tough technically) so we can have a single source of truth?

thanks a lot :D

Comment: There are quite a lot of questions in here. You might get better answers by being more specific with your question.

Comment: Hi Eslam, thanks for your contribution to UXSE. There are quite a few questions here, and not all of them specifically relate to user experience directly, since there might be other dependencies like technical constraints and business requirements involved as well. It is probably easiest to break them into different questions and that way you can also provide more details about each specific question and get more detailed answers. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to say that all the hype around how users react to changes like this is real. You should try to find some users that are low experience and test them or at least watch them use the new site